# Reaction between bromobenzene and methyllithium to yeld toluene: possible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I was solving some reactivity problems, and I was asked to prepare toluene from bromobenzene.

While the suggested solution of the problem involves the preparation of a Grignard reagent, followed by a reaction with methyl bromide, I was wondering:

Could the same compound be prepared with the straightforward reaction between bromobenzene and methyl lithium?

I tried to search some similar reactions, but I found nothing for both the possible ways.

Comment: Probably not, bromobenzene might not be electrophilic enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MeLi certainly does lithium-halogen exchange and in the presence of MeI takes bromobenzenes to toluenes   Synth. Comm. **2001** 2323

If you're asking whether the MeBr produced by the exchange can act as the methylating agent? I have never seen this reported but maybe someone else can pull up a reference.